# Shipping Method still show after disabled

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.4.2

My Magento is upgrade from 2.3.2 to version 2.4.2
and I try to disable all flat rate before adding new one. after I disabled all of flat rate and clear cache. those flat rate still there
where can I find source code to take it out. because disabled it in admin wont work.

for multi flat shipping extension that I use is Meetanshi Flat Shipping

[image: Shipping Method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change setting on Ship to Applicable Countries from "All Allowed Countries" to "Specific Countries" And it dissappear now

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following commands and then check in private browser one's.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Answer (score 0):

For that First, you check Meetanshi Flat Shipping is compatible With Magento 2.4.2 latest version if yes then follow this step,

```
rm -rf generated/
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

After running this command check guest mode or Private browser

Comment: I think it's not from the extension. when I inspect element it's call the one that show is bestway_tablerate but I already disable it and I try to clear every cache but it's not working